# macOS app review process: Touch Bar functionality in metadata

Tags: macos, applications, xcode, app-store-connect, metadata

I have a macOS app that get bug fixed. But the latest Apple review process drives me a bit insane. They always tell me that my app's metadata indicates Touch Bar functionality which my app do not have.

So my App have no Touch Bar functions, also it do not use any `NSTouchBar` methods. I actually never build any Touch bar app – so is there a capability or something that I could have possibly activated and what Apple now indicates there "should" be Touch Bar integration but there is none?

I asked them where my metadata is indicating Touch Bar functionality but they only redirects me to the App Store Connect Developer Help. Which do not help me. Even when I search for Touch Bar there is no match.

So I have no idea what Apple want from me. I wrote them now that they maybe misread the description. I am using a Status Bar Menu in my App – maybe they had read "Touch Bar" instead of "Status Bar"...

Or am I missing something that I have possibly accidentally activated?

This is the response from Apple:

> Your app does not achieve the core functionality described in your
>   app’s metadata.
>
> Specifically, your app’s metadata is still indicating that your app is
>   using touchBar functionality.
>
> The user is provided the option to select this functionality within
>   the app. Only after attempting to use this functionality is the user
>   told that it is not available without an additional install. It will
>   be necessary to remove this functionality from the app.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage, I'd advise you to submit a technical support incident. As a paid member of the Apple Developer Program, you are eligible for 2 technical support incidents in a year. It involves getting access to an engineer from Apple's development team and basically get code level assistance.

- [Requesting Technical Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/)

> A Technical Support Incident (TSI) is a request for code-level support for Apple frameworks, APIs, and tools, and is available to members of the Apple Developer Program, Apple Developer Enterprise Program, and MFi Program. Submit a TSI if you cannot fix a bug, have trouble implementing a specific technology, or have other questions about your code. Your incident will be assigned to a Developer Technical Support engineer who can help troubleshoot your code or investigate possible workarounds to fast-track your development. Support is provided in English via email, typically within three business days.

You can have an engineer look through the issue and advise you in what may be possibly causing trouble getting your app approved.